# Error occurs when attemping to import any module in the PyQt5 package

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyqt5, python-import, qtcore

I have created a python file, test.py, that only imports sys, PyQt5 and PyQt5.QtCore and then prints sys.path and the file associated with these imports.  Upon executing test.py the following error occurs.

```
['c:\\TestImport', 'c:\\Users\\vh942e\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\\pythonFiles', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vh942e\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\vh942e\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 391, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\vh942e\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 272, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\TestImport\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The test.py file is the only file in the C:\TestImport directory. I have run it as a script as well as trying to import in the python REPL with no success.

I have reinstalled PyQt5 but the error still continues.

When the program is executed, PyQt5 is found and its file is printed. However, PyQt5.QtCore is not found.

The QtCore.pyd and QtCore.pyi files are located in the PyQt5 folder in the C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages directory. So it appears that python is not looking in the PyQt5 folder to find QtCore or any other modules in that folder.

I do not understand why python is not looking in the recognized PyQt5 folder. Any suggestions would be helpful.

The test.py file contains the following code.

import sys
print(sys.path)
import PyQt5
print(PyQt5.**file**)
from PyQt5 import QtCore
print(QtCore.**file**)

Comment: BTW, I am using Python 3.7.3

Comment: A complete uninstall and install of anaconda failed to fix the problem.